# PHP. New instantiated object call only __destruct() if variable for it was used for instantiation same class early

Tags: php

I want to test how `__destruct` method works, this is my test class:

```
class A
{
    public static $x = 1;
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "construct\n";
    }
    public function test()
    {
        echo self::$x . "\n";
        self::$x++;
    }
    public function __destruct()
    {
        exit("destruct\n");
    }
}
```

Now I try to instantiate several objects and call `test()` method:

```
$first = new A();
$first->test();
$first->test();

$second = new A();
$second->test();
$second->test();

$first = new A();
$first->test();
$first->test();
```

The output:

```
construct
1
2
construct
3
4
construct
destruct
destruct
```

Why last `$first` object returns only "destruct" ? It seems it call only `__destruct()` method. This code was tested on PHP 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reinitialized the variable `$first`, you destroyed the old instance, so the method `__destruct()` was called terminating the script with `exit("destruct\n");`.

Then inside the `exit` another `__destruct()` was called terminating the process, preventing the last `__destruct()` to be executed.

```
$first = new A();
$first->test();
$first->test();

$second = new A();
$second->test();
$second->test();

$first = new A(); //First __destruct call and exit
$first->test(); //Not executed
$first->test();
```